# Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\aleja\.android\debug.keystore": Detect premature EOF

Tags: debugging, dart, flutter, android-virtual-device

Every time I try to load an app to a virtual device, wheter I'm using react-native or flutter, vs code or android studio, it always happens!!

```
Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store `C:\Users\aleja\.android\debug.keystore`: Detect premature EOF
```

I tried running it on vs code and android studio, it happens on both

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that your key alias does not exist for your keystore file.

This answer should fix your signing issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check your keystore file for first, in your example you are creating file with name `my-release-key.keystore`. If its correct and really present in Directory `Users/bournewang/Documents/Project` then check `alias`, in your example its `-alias alias_name`, but in config you specified `alias mike`.